# Flutter - How can I make a square widget take up its maximum possible space in a row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-row

I have a `CustomPaint` that needs to be a 1:1 square, and I need to put this in a `Row`. The horizontal and vertical space available can vary, so I need both the length and width of the square to be the smallest maximum constraint.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

I've tried using `LayoutBuilder` for this:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    ...,
    LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final size = min(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
        return SizedBox(
          width: size,
          height: Size,
          child: CustomPaint(...),
        ),
      },
    ),
  ]
),
```

This, however, doesn't work, because `Row` provides unbounded horizontal constraints (`maxWidth == double.infinity`). Using the `FittedBox` widget also fails for the same reason.

Wrapping the `LayoutBuilder` in an `Expanded` widget provides it with a bounded maximum width, but I need to have another widget next to it in the `Row`, so this is not appropriate. `Flexible` behaves like `Expanded` in this case, as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can get what you want from the AspectRatio widget... if you tell it 1:1, then it tries to make a square unless completely not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, `AspectRatio` uses the height to calculate the width. This is not appropriate in this situation, as it doesn't take any width constraints into account.

Comment: This may not have answered the question as written, but it did solve the issue I had when I found this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below, using Align widget restrains the widget to a square  :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              final size = min(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Container(
                  height: size,
                  width: size,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        // Expanded(
        //   flex: 1,
        //   child: Container(),
        // ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I said in the question, I cannot use `Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working this issue by moving the responsibility of keeping the widget square up the tree. Widgets that were using the square widget knew more about what other things they were showing and were more capable of giving it the right constraints.

Comment: Answers are still welcome, as I haven't really worked out the answer to my question yet, I've just worked around it.